# How to backup Log Analytics workspace or recover?

Tags: azure, backup, azure-log-analytics, disaster-recovery, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm just wondering how Azure deal with backing up the Log Analyticsworkspaces.
I just want to design a log audit to collect logs from different resources and have them in the LA workspaces.However, I want to be sure if there is a recovery plan by default by Azure or If there is way that I can design a backup in azure to backup the LA workspaces.

Microsoft azure promises to [recover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/delete-workspace)  the deleted workspaces within 14 days but this feature does not fit to my scenario. I need more time period that I'm confident on to recover the backup data.For example two years or more.
Any idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The feature that Microsoft provides is a "Soft Delete" option, it's not a "Backup" feature of the workspace.
After a delete, you can recover the workspace until 14 days after the delete action. After that the data will get purged. (As also described in the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/delete-workspace) you shared)

To backup your data, there are a few options to duplicate your data to other destinations:

1. When configuring the [Diagnostic Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=portal) of the different sources, you can specify multiple destinations, either a secondary Log Analytics Workspace or a Storage Account or streaming it to other places using Event Hub.
2. You can configure a [data export rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal) on the Log Analytics Workspace to export the selected tables to a Storage Account or streaming it to other places using Event Hub.
3. Export data from a Log Analytics workspace to a storage account by [using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app)
4. Schedule export of data based on a log query you define with the Log Analytics query API. Use Azure Data Factory, Azure Functions, or Azure Logic Apps to orchestrate queries in your workspace and export data to a destination.
5. One-time export to a local machine by using a PowerShell script.